Django __main__.Profile doesn't declare an explicit app label
So I am working on Django and have not much experience with it yet. So far I've set up alright but now I've run into this error:

RuntimeError: Model class main.Profile doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

The INSTALLED_APPS looks like:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'tweets.apps.tweetsConfig',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'de Sitter vacua',
 ]

I'm completely flabbergasted at this because I have no idea what the issue here is.
I tried going through stackexchange Q&As and am clueless as to what the issue here is. Tried some solutions but it doesn't seem to be working.

So wehere do you declare  model, can you share the filetree?

First, ensure that you created your app correctly using the command:
python manage.py startapp appname

This will create your app in your project root directory assuming you created your project correctly using django-admin startproject projectname . The app directory would contain files such as models.py, views.py etc. Then write your Model Profile in the models.py of the relevant app.
Include your app in your INSTALLED_APPS list (preferably as a dotted path to a configuration class). In your case, I suspect that 'tweets.apps.tweetsConfig' is actually 'tweets.apps.TweetsConfig' So verify this and correct it.
Also you didn't mention what app throws this error. Is it your tweets app or de Sitter vacua (is this an app?). The naming of the latter looks a little strange, do verify if it's one of your apps.
